# How do I resolve VSCode syntax error for python script that runs fine in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and learning python using VSCode as my IDE.

- For an exercise, I created a python script in VSCode that tells the user in what year they will turn 100 years old. Below is the code:

```
# gets user age and prints the year user will be 100 years old

import datetime

cDate = datetime.datetime.now()
cYear = int(cDate.year)

uName = input("Hi, what is your name?: ")
print ("Hello " + uName)
print ("I will tell you what year you will turn 100 years!")
uAge = int(input("How old are you?: "))

year100 = cYear - uAge + 100

print ("You will be 100 years old in the year " + str(year100) + "!.")
```

- The code is supposed to ask user for name, age then calculate and print out the year the user will be 100 years of age.
- When I ran it on VSCode, I got the error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Education/phyton/exercises/age in 100 years.py", line 3, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/datetime.py", line 8, in <module>
    import math as _math
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Education/phyton/exercises/math.py", line 1
    Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- I believe the problem may lie in the VSCode python configuration having tested the same code in IDLE where it ran perfectly.
- So far I have installed python 3.8 (previously had 3.7 installed) with no effect.

My system details include:
- macOS Catalina
- Python 2.7 and 3.8 installed

Please do not hesitate to ask if you have any other questions.

Comment: The problem is in the first line of `/Users/me/Documents/Education/phyton/exercises/math.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the directory with your `age.py` file, you also have a `math.py` file. The `datetime` module (which you use by typing `import datetime`) is looking for the Python math module, `math.py`. But it's finding your `math.py` file first.

The issue is in that file, not in your `age.py` file. There's apparently a line that starts with `Python 3.7.0...` that isn't valid Python syntax. You should probably rename `math.py` to something like `my_math.py`, which should resolve the issue.

Comment: thank you so much! I simply deleted the math.py file. I imagine I have to be careful with the names I give to python scripts then to avoid these type of clashes.

Comment: I'm glad this was useful.